# JSF - Validation fails on SelectOneMenu (error is not valid) - Hibernate related?

Tags: hibernate, validation, jsf, jsf-2

I already read a lot of questions here about this same problem, and I can assure you that is not the EQUALs method, and also, it is not a problem as the bean scope. So, lets see what is happening.

I have this selectOne, that is working 'partially'

```
                <p:selectOneMenu id="acao" converter="#{acaoConverter}" value="#{prospectoRadarController.acaoSelecionada}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['label.selecione.item']}" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems var="a" itemValue="#{a}" itemLabel="#{a.descricao}" value="#{acaoController.listarAcoesEmAberto()}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

So I have the 'Acao' entity. All the entities are completly valid, as the HTML of the select is also correct (the value is the correct ID of the entity).

The data that I imported (using an SQL file) check out the last two lines:

```
            INSERT INTO com_acao VALUES (190, 0.00, '2012-12-31', '2012-12-31', '2012-12-31', 'SELECIONADOS 2012-1', 0, 1, 1);
            ALTER SEQUENCE com_acao_id_seq RESTART WITH 191;
```

Ok then, If i INSERT a new entity, it inserts correctly, with the right ID, and everything works fine.

**THE PROBLEM**: On that SelectOneMenu, if I choose an entity that was imported with the SQL file, it works. If I choose a new entity, that I saved using the system, I get the:

```
  javax.faces.component.UISelectOne.INVALID
```

Validation error. So again, the equals is not broken. My best bet is that this is Hibernate related. But.... HOW come it adds, filters, searches for the entity, and no errors occurrs? Only the validation error is happening ? :(

This is the entity ID declaration:

```
   public class Acao {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Integer id;
```

Thanks !
My Repositories are Spring Data's PagingAndSorting interface. I don´t know if this is a relevant information... If you guys need any info, just ask! Thanks again!

**UPDATE**
The method that loads the list of "Acao" to be displayed on the SelectItems:

```
public List<Acao> listarAcoesEmAberto() {
    return acaoService.listarAcoesEmAberto();
}
```

With is this Query executed:

```
@Query("select a from Acao a where a.dataFinal is null OR current_date() <= a.dataFinal")
public List<Acao> listarAcoesEmAberto();
```

**UPDATE 2** The converter methods:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
    if (arg2 == null || arg2.equals("")) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        return baseService.findOne((PK) new SimpleTypeConverter().convertIfNecessary(arg2, ReflectUtil.getPrimaryKeyField(entityClass).getType()));
    } catch (TypeMismatchException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
    if (arg2 == null) {
        return "";
    }

    return arg2.toString();
}
```

NOTE: this is a generic converter. The real converter is:

@Component
@Scope("request")
public class AcaoConverter extends BaseConverter implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired
public AcaoConverter(AcaoService acaoService) {
    super(acaoService, Acao.class); 
}
```

So its the same converter for ALL of the entities. And it works.
Why not for this particular case? :(

**UPDATE 3** Lets see the problem better...

This is the imported row from the sql file:
[image: a]

This is a row that I created using the program:
[image: 2]

This is the same on the database (so it is commited):
[image: 3]

This is the SELECT:
[image: 4]

The HTML:
[image: 5]

SUCESS CASE (selecting the imported row):
[image: 6]

ERROR CASE (selecting the created row):
[image: 7]

**UPDATE 4** WOW ! I tested with some other entities that where imported, and... Some of them doesn´t work. So, bottom line: new entities doesn´t work, and some imported entities doesn´t work! Looking at the database, they are all fine data, nothing missing or  violations. So wierd!

Another thing.. with autoComplete component it works!!!! (everything works)

Comment: The xhtml looks alright, except for the empty value for the first item. I am not sure how your converter works, but that could be an issue, I normally use #{null} for that. Other than that, please post the code for both of your beans, it might be a little easier to help you that way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No empty value is not a problem. :( I´ve update the question. Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe your problem is in the converter? Please post the code for both methods: getAsObject and getAsString

Comment: Have you tried replacing the Primefaces select one menu with a `<h:selectOneMenu>`?  I have experienced troublesome bugs with the Primefaces selectOneMenu component in the past.  Also, is there any way you can rule out using the Paging functionality?  Paging uses scrolling result sets which would require an open transaction.  Its possible that there is some issue with how that is being used or configured

Comment: @maple_shaft p:selectOneMenu used to be buggy indeed. However, I've been using it for at least the last six months without any issues. But I guess it doesn't hurt to try h:selectOneMenu, eh?

Comment: Andre: Ok, updated the post.

maple_shaft: I´ll try that. Didn´t understand about the paging. You´re talking about Spring Data right? Well, I don´t implement an concret class, only an interface. So the magic is done by Spring Data. Sorry if I didn´t  answer your question correctly.

Comment: And your toString() method just returns the primary key, right?

Comment: Yes it does Andre. And also, this does not explain why it works with entities generated by the import sql files, AND NOT the new entities genareted by the software! Very strange.

Comment: It is indeed. Are the transactions being committed for sure? I mean, can you query the database and see the new records added using the system? Can you put a breakpoint on your converter and see what's going on when you submit the form?

Comment: Yes, I did that. I can see the row on the datatabe. I also debug the converter, and it brings the right object!!! I can´t find a logical explanation for this. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23221/discussion-between-andre-and-d34d-d3v1l)

Comment: Sure that the converter doesn't randomly return `null`?

Comment: Yes BalusC ! Pretty sure.

Comment: If you can´t help me BalusC,  i´´ll post an answer talking about the work around that I did (using autocomplete with dropdown=true), and mark it as accepted. You're my last hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

no solution for selectOneMenu.
So I used an autoComplete with dropdown (true).

It works fine.

So, this is not really a solution, but a workaround.
Thanks all for the help.